# Multiple Tweet buttons on same page performance issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I am developing a web page where we need to show multiple tweet share buttons for each diary entry on the webpage, however I am getting a performance issue with what I am trying.

Currently the page content is rendered by jQuery and for each post I am adding a tweet button like this:

```
$.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
html = '<p>this is a diary entry</p>';
html += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-related="bmywebsite" data-lang="en" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>';
})

$('#usersDiary').html(html);

// Used to add the Twitter.js include
var twitterScript   = document.createElement("script");
twitterScript.type  = "text/javascript";
twitterScript.src   = "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
$('#usersDiary').append(twitterScript);
```

This works fairly OK but i started to notice that with the more diary entries on the page the performance goes down hill, when I look at the Networking for the page I am seeing lots of these entries.

[image: Network Image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to enable multiple tweet buttons but reducing the number of network calls?

Thanks Aaron

Comment: You can enable caching of images.. If thats done then it won't hit the network each time it plants a button

Comment: I dont think its a caching of the image issue if you look at the screen shot the webpage is calling the remote widgets.js multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Try [Socialite.js](http://socialitejs.com/), it will handle your requests asynchronously and with optimized JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply this looks quite interesting however it still seems a bit of a performance hit the more you scroll.